# fputcsv function and Forms

Tags: php

I'm trying to process my Form submit values to a .csv file using the `fputcsv` function. I'm not getting any errors and no Form values have been saved to the data.csv file. Can anyone see a problem as to what i'm doing wrong?

**Form**

```
<label for="location">How many Locations?</label> 
<input id="location" name="loc" /><br />

<select id="when" name="day">
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="osecom" name="osecom" value="Yes" /> 
<label for="osecom">Online</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="item1yes" name="item1yes" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="checkbox" id="item1no" name="item1no" value="No" /> No<br />
<label for="chkitem1">mobile</label> 

<input type="checkbox" id="item2yes" name="item2yes" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="checkbox" id="item2no" name="item2no" value="No" /> No<br />
<label for="chkitem2">policy? </label> 

<input type="submit" title="Submit Form" value="" />
```

**php code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $data = implode(',', $_POST);
    if( $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a') ){
        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }
    fclose($fp);        

}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, this may help you debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use implode(',', $_POST)!

$_POST is array and fputcsv() expects second param to be array not string!

Better use this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = array_values($_POST); // get only values
    if( $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a') ){
        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Note that by saving only values you will have problems reading the csv if parameters in $_POST switch places so it would be better to save first row with headers:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = array_values($_POST); // get only values
    $headers = array_keys($_POST); // keys are headers 
    if( $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a') ){
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);
        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Edit:
I have noticed that in your form you are using checkboxes where radio buttons would fit better like for field "mobile?" and "policy?"

Comment: That's something I noticed too... I'm just following a graphic design and they wanted checkboxes :/ thanks for the help, i'm going to try it out now.

Comment: Question only the inputbox types seem to have quotes around the data all other types don't. how can I remove quotes to make the data cleaner

Comment: this is how CSV format works, if field does not contain CSV specific chars like " , (or ;) and space it is not wrapped in "" to reduce the file length, but if it does then in order to protect CSV data integrity it is wrapped in ""